# Downloading XML file from URL returning NIL in NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to download an XML file from this URL [www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=5.6283473,50.5348043,5.6285261,50.534884]](http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*%5Bmaxspeed=*%5D%5Bbbox=5.6283473,50.5348043,5.6285261,50.534884%5D)
but it returns `nil` to `NSData`. My code is:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=5.6283473,50.5348043,5.6285261,50.534884]"];
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
        NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
}
```

The error says "**The file “xapi” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.**"

Please help how can I download the XML returned from the URL and parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Just added `http://` to the beginning of the link and it returns proper data. Wow!